# that sentence appear every time how do i skip that "Error establishing a database connection"

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I am new in web developing so don't make jokes please
I got this "Error establishing a database connection"
every time I try I added "multisite true "its first time to open WordPress ok so I have been trying to find the solution for 72 hours but nothing happens can someone help me its about a  paid course and I want to finish it thx everyone

Comment: Your wp-config.php file in the root of your site has your database credentials.  Test those credentials to make sure they work.

Comment: seems like having issue with DB credential so please try to reset user/password for particular DB and change in wp-config.php accordingly

Answer (score 1):

when we install wordpress ,code for wp-config.php is generated , this file containes database settings. you can confirm database settings here